# MVC Retrieve and Send Data - Money Conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api

I am trying to do a conversion using Google API. However I am getting and Index was out of range error and the form collection is not collecting the data as I want (amount, currencyFrom, currencyTo). What am I doing wrong?

Exchange Rate Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency> currency = CurrencyManager.Instance.getAllCurrencies().ToList();
        return View(currency);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();

            string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}", (string)fc[1].ToUpper(), (string)fc[2].ToUpper(), (string)fc[0]);

            string response = web.DownloadString(url);

            Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*.\\d*)");
            Match match = regex.Match(response);

            decimal rate = System.Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value);
            ViewBag["rate"] = (string)fc[0] + " " + (string)fc[1] + "  =  " + rate + " " + (string)fc[2];
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Exchange Rate View:

```
 @model IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exchange Rates";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_ExchangeRatePartial");
```

Partial View:

```
       @model IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>

    <br /> <br /> 

    @Html.BeginForm())
    {
       Convert: <input type="text" size="5" value="1" />
        @Html.DropDownList("Currency", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem{ Text = p.ID, Value = p.Name})) 
 to  
       @Html.DropDownList("Currency", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.ID, Value = p.Name}))
        <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" name="Convert" />
    }

    @if(ViewData["rate"] != null)
    {
        @ViewData["rate"]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is considered a complex object. It's best that you use a viewmodel for that, so you can also benefit from the the model binder.

```
public class CurrencyViewModel {
    public string ConversionRate {get;set;}
    public IList<int> Currencies {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency> CurrencyList {get;set;}
}
```

you then need to change your view to

```
@model CurrencyViewModel 
Convert: @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.ConversionRate, new { @size="5" } />
@Html.DropDownList("Currencies", 
    Model.CurrencyList.Select(p => 
        new SelectListItem{ Text = p.ID, Value = p.Name}))
@Html.DropDownList("Currencies", 
    Model.CurrencyList.Select(p => 
        new SelectListItem{ Text = p.ID, Value = p.Name}))
```

then your controller method to

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var currency = CurrencyManager.Instance.getAllCurrencies().ToList();
    return View(new CurrencyViewModel { CurrencyList = currency });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CurrencyViewModel input)
{
    // you can then access the input like this
    var rate = input.ConversionRate;
    foreach(var currency in input.Currencies) {
        var id = currency; 
        // currency is an int equivalent to CommonLayer.Currency.ID
    }
}
```

Comment: can I still use this model too (which I am retreving the names of the different currencies from the database): 
@model IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>

Comment: Right I forgot to add the GET method, please see my updated answer

Comment: Had to make some minor changes to fit my project but I understood the concept better and made it work. Thanks a lot for your help!